# Libgdx Desktop Launcher blank

Tags: java, libgdx

Just starting Libgdx and java game development. Got a little bit of code to try and write a sprite sheet moving animation person, just started it so not finished by when i try an run it the single sprite drawing is not running, nothing is the desktop appliction is just black.

Desktop Launcher:

```
package com.mkgame.game1.desktop;

import com.MKgames.OptionScreen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.mkgame.game1.Game1;

public class DesktopLauncher extends Game1{
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "Game1";
        cfg.width = 960;
        cfg.height = 540;

        new LwjglApplication(new Game1 (), cfg);

    }
}
```

Main java class 'Game1':

```
package com.mkgame.game1;

import com.MKgames.FarmerAsset;
import com.MKgames.OptionScreen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Game1 extends ApplicationAdapter {

    public OptionScreen game_screen;

    public void create() {
        FarmerAsset.load();
    }
}
```

Game screen:

```
package com.MKgames;

import sun.java2d.loops.DrawGlyphListAA.General;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class OptionScreen implements Screen{

    GameMain game;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    SpriteBatch batch;

    int farmerX;

    public OptionScreen(GameMain game){
        this.game = game;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(true, 1920, 1080);

        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        farmerX = 960-85;

    }


    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.95F, 0.95F, 0.95F, 0.95F);


        camera.update();
        generalUpdate();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();
            batch.draw(FarmerAsset.farmer1, farmerX, 200);
        batch.end();


    }


    public void generalUpdate() {
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)||Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)){
            farmerX -= 5;
        }
        else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)||Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)){
            farmerX += 5;   
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
public class Game1 extends ApplicationAdapter {
```

to

```
public class Game1 extends Game {
```

Create an instance of OptionScreen in Game:

```
public OptionScreen game_screen;

public void create() {
    FarmerAsset.load();
    game_screen = new OptionScreen(this);
    setScreen(game_screen);
}
```

And it should be good to go.

Comment: just tried that but i get an error on 'new OptionScreen(this);' :The constructor OptionScreen(Game1) is undefined

Comment: Wait a second, what on earth is GameMain? That should be Game1 according to your current class hierarchy.

Comment: Also, please make sure you dispose the SpriteBatch on the dispose() function of the Game.

Comment: Sorry, i dont under stand where GameMain should be changed?

Comment: In OptionScreen. I don't even know what GameMain is.

Comment: I have changed that but still an error on  'new OptionScreen(this);' :The constructor OptionScreen(GameMain) is undefined

Comment: change GameMain to Game1

Comment: THank u very much 4 your help so far. Ok reorganised myself a bit but err so many errors: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.draw(SpriteBatch.java:576)
 at com.MKgames.OptionScreen.render(OptionScreen.java:43)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)

Comment: That looks like an error in FarmerAsset.farmer1 not being loaded properly, you should check that out. Possibly something is wrong with the load() function.